# FlightCrew reporting errors in "amzn" CSS links

Tags: kindle

I have an Amazon Ebook in which I display nature photos that I have collected. Now several years later I am updating the book with some new images.

I ran Flight Crew 0.7.2 on my epub and was surprised to the following errors:

TEST-43D.epub/OEBPS/Text/Dedication.xhtml - unable to find validator for simple type of attribute 'media'

Flight Crew reports similar errors for all links to the following lines in the CSS section of  every page of the document (FYI:I am using Sigil 0.9.9):

line 8 
line 9

The line above this section in every page: line 7  doesn't trigger an error message.

I suspected that the "amzn" references were the problem; but I do have a "amzn-mobi.css" and "amzn-kf8.css" pages in the CSS section.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with these lines to cause Flight Crew to flag them?

Thanks!